# Notification from FCM is sometimes displayed in iOS notification tray

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project where we are using Firebase Cloud Messaging for push notifications. The following JSON is currently being produced by the backend API and sent to FCM:

```
{
  "priority": "normal",
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "dry_run": false,
  "time_to_live": 3600,
  "notification": {
    "body_loc_key": "MyCustomNotificationId"
  },
  "data": {
    // contains notification data
  },
  "registration_ids": [

  ]
}
```

This notification should be silent, meaning it should be only received when the iOS application is in the foreground, however sometimes on some devices this notification also finds its way to the iOS notification tray with the app being in the background as if it had parameters to be displayed there.

I have found out the `body_loc_key` attribute must be present to iOS devices, otherwise the notification won't ever hit the device, whether the application is in the foreground or background.

The problem occured on the following devices:

- Apple iPhone 5,
- Apple iPhone 6,

with the possibility of others being affected as well.

Is there a different configuration for the JSON sent to FCM you have used with a success, where the notifications are only being sent to the device when the application is in the foreground?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with the FCM payload for sime time we have found out the problem was actually the `body_loc_key` attribute all along.

In order for a notification to be silent and still sent to an apple device, the payload must meet the following criteria:

- `priority` must be set to `normal`,
- `content_available` must be set to `true`,
- `notification` attribute must contain data, but should it contain the `body_loc_key` attribute it must be set to an empty string - `""`.

**Working payload examples:**

```
// Example one
{
  "priority": "normal",
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "dry_run": false,
  "time_to_live": 3600,
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
    "body_loc_key": ""
  },
  "data": {
    // contains notification data
  },
  "registration_ids": [
  ]
}

// Example two
// (note that body_loc_key has been replaced with badge)
{
  "priority": "normal",
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "dry_run": false,
  "time_to_live": 3600,
  "content_available": true,
  "notification": {
    "badge": 10
  },
  "data": {
    // contains notification data
  },
  "registration_ids": [
  ]
}
```

Changing the `body_loc_key` to an empty string pretty much fixed the issue. On top of that we have also found out the following about [other](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) attributes of the `notification` attribute:

- `badge` may be present and is processed, notification remains silent,
- `title_loc_key` has no effect, notification remains silent,
- `body_loc_args` has no effect, notification remains silent.

All three additions apply to scenario where the precedent criteria have been met (empty `body_loc_key` if/when present, etc.).

Comment: Please give a feedback if you decide to downvote an answer. I provided an actual solution to the problem I was having, unlike other answers, don't know what is the issue here.

Answer (score -1):

The reason why your notification is being sent as **display-message** and not as **silent-message** is because you are using the `notification` payload.
In particular you are using the `body_loc_key`.

You wrote that you read that `body_loc_key` is required to send silent-messages.
**This is not true.**
Can you please link the page where you found this?

Comment: When the `notification` payload was empty the notification never came to the device. Based on our tests, it has to contain something.